# In wpf, how can I get the next control in the tab order

Tags: wpf, tab-ordering

I know how to ***set*** the focus to the next control in the tab order, but I don't actually want to change focus... I just want to ***get*** the next control in the tab order (perhaps get the previous, first and last ones too.)  So... howyadodat?

M

Comment: By the way, how do you set the focus to the next UIElement?

Comment: Idea: to write a traversal algorithm that adds UIElements to the list in the Tab order (once). Then look up the control in the list and see who's next.

Answer (score 1):

`PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Next)` doesn't work as @Cameron said. My wrapper code based on @Randolpho 's post is now working well.

I tried several patterns and finally concluded I have to make sure `container` is actually one of the parents of `e` to avoid unexpected results.

```
/// <summary>
/// Get next tab order element.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="e">The element to get next tab order</param>
/// <param name="container">The container element owning 'e'. Make sure this is a container of 'e'.</param>
/// <param name="goDownOnly">True if search only itself and inside of 'container'; otherwise false.
/// If true and next tab order element is outside of 'container', result in null.</param>
/// <returns>Next tab order element or null if not found</returns>
public DependencyObject GetNextTab(DependencyObject e, DependencyObject container, bool goDownOnly)
{
    var navigation = typeof(FrameworkElement)
        .GetProperty("KeyboardNavigation", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .GetValue(null);

    var method = navigation
        .GetType()
        .GetMethod("GetNextTab", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    return method.Invoke(navigation, new object[] { e, container, goDownOnly }) as DependencyObject;
}
```

Ex.)

```
var nextElement = GetNextTab(textbox1, window, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible to have the next control in tab order, but you can loop on the children collection and use the  `KeyboardNavigation.GetIsTabStop(..)` `KeyboardNavigation.GetTabIndex()` to create an helper for thet.

Answer (score 0):

[`PredictFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.predictfocus.aspx) was supposed to get Tab support in .NET 4, but the [current MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusnavigationdirection.aspx) implies it hasn't. That may be a documentation oversight, however; I haven't tried it, but you could give it a shot.

If that doesn't work, there's a private method on `KeyboardNavigation` that may do you some good; you'll have to use reflection to call it, and you'll need the proper code access permissions to do it, but it might work. .NET Reflector reveals the signature as follows:

```
private DependencyObject GetNextTab(DependencyObject e, DependencyObject container, bool goDownOnly)
```

Where `e` is the element for which you want to get the next tab, and `container` is its parent container. I'm not 100% sure what `goDownOnly` does, but I *guess* that it indicates that you don't want to leave the parent container. The method will return null if there isn't a next tab for that element.

Keep in mind, this is a private method; highly susceptible to change come the next version.

**Edit:** you'll need an instance of `KeyboardNavigation`! Totally forgot about that. There's a static one at `FrameworkElement.KeyboardNavigation`, but it's also internal, so reflection to get at it.

Comment: The documentation isn't an oversight -- it still throws an `InvalidEnumArgumentException` in .NET 4